# Is there a Java structure that allows .contains lookups for serializable objects without actually storing them?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I'm looking for some sort of structure that would allow me to make contains() - lookups but wouldn't store the original values in order to reduce the storage overhead.

The use case is filtering of events in a large stream. I can't possibly store all encountered values, but knowing that certain events occurred before is valuable.

Java Sets or HashMaps store the keys, thus producing way too much overhead to be a viable solution for huge volumes of data.

Storing the actual values is not essential to allow for such look-ups. One example of that would be a Trie that can be used to match a multitude of different strings but requires significantly less storage than the individual strings combined.s

Comment: What exactly do you mean by serializable and .contains? Also, I'd be quite interested in seeing a Trie implementation that actually uses less storage.

Comment: "Storing the actual values is not essential to allow for such look-ups." It is, in the general case. If you are doing this for, e.g. strings, you can store values which in some sense summarise the string (hash code, length, first letter etc), but you will get collisions of these values between unequal values for which these summary values happen to be equal. To truly determine if a particular string has been seen before, you are going to need that string; otherwise, you can only determine it to some probability.

Comment: Andy, I used a Trie as an example. You can easily "reconstruct" the original string by traversing the nodes of the trie and is guaranteed not to cause any collisions.

Comment: Stefan: I wrote an implementation once. Unfortunately, this is very hard to do in Java. If you follow OOP principles and create objects for nodes, the heap explodes and ends up growing exponentially because of object overhead. A slimmer implementation with off-heap storage based on pointer arrays might actually be only slightly bigger than the input data, most probably way smaller because of de-duplication of prefixes. Add some on the fly compression of some sort and you're good to go.
If I can't find a good implementation, I'll try and come up with something myself.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're after is a guarantee that a value has *not* yet been seen, a bloom filter may suit your needs.

Guava has an implementation, in that case:

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained#bloomfilter

Comment: nice! Thanks for the info. Interesting stuff. Upvoted!

Comment: Very cool. This is awesome for quick, probabilistic filtering.